# Open-source .NET neural network library?

Tags: .net, neural-network

Can anyone recommend a good open-source .NET neural network library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Best .NET neural network library is AForge

Links:

[MainPage](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/)

[CodeProject-Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/aforge_neuro.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

Encog is a free open source neural network API for both Java and DotNet.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog

Answer (score 5):

[**NeuronDotNet**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neurondotnet/?source=navbar)  It is not as broad in its scope as AForge, but its exclusive focus on NN makes it maybe more readily accessible, and possibly more featured in this area.

**Update**: (December 2012)
NeuronDotNet's old repository at http://neurondotnet.freehostia.com is defunct.
The most recent source code, **Version 3.0** is available on sourceforge, but **this project is effectively inactive**. Apparently, its original developer, and sole contributor, Vijeth Dinesha, has stopped updating and improving this code base.  Thank you, Vijeth!  Maybe someone will, some day,  pick-up from where you left.  Indeed, NeuronDotNet is a relatively mature framework and its simplicity and single focus make it attractive, compared with other frameworks where Neural Nets are just one feature/module therein.

Answer (score 5):

In case this helps anybody else, MS SQL has [pretty robust built-in Neural Network support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174941.aspx) as part of [Data Mining Analysis Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175595.aspx).

I know MS SQL isn't open source, but odds are if you are using .NET your data may already be in SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a list of F# related resources for open source .NET machine learning.

http://fsharp.org/machine-learning/

Frameworks available on NuGet: (The content below was taken directly from the above referenced URL for persistence purposes.)

- Accord.MachineLearning - Contains Support Vector Machines, Decision Trees, Naive Bayesian models, K-means, Gaussian Mixture models and general algorithms such as Ransac, Cross-validation and Grid-Search for machine-learning applications. This package is part of the Accord.NET Framework.
- Encog Machine Learning Framework - An advanced neural network and machine learning framework. Encog contains classes to create a wide variety of networks, as well as support classes to normalize and process data for these neural networks. Encog trains using multithreaded resilient propagation. Encog can also make use of a GPU to further speed processing time. A GUI based workbench is also provided to help model and train neural networks.
- Numl - A machine learning library intended to ease the use of using standard modeling techniques for both prediction and clustering

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see: [FANN](http://leenissen.dk/fann/) fits both of the categories.

Answer (score 2):

Download [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and convert from the jar file (Java bytecode) to .NET Framework (managed) dll through [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/). Weka is aknowledged by many as a very good open-source library for machine learning. It includes neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

https://dotnet.github.io/infer/
Infer.NET is a framework for running Bayesian inference in graphical models.